# Proving row equivalence between Matrix and Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $F$ be a field with $a,b,c \in F$.

Prove that this matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & a & a^2           \\[0.3em]
       1 & b           & b^2 \\[0.3em]
       1           & c & c^2
     \end{bmatrix}

is row equivalent to the Identity Matrix.

---

**My thoughts:**

I know in order to show that two matrix are row equivalent, you need to be able to transform one into the other using Elementary Row Operations. However I don't see an easy way to do so... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possibly prove that the determinant is nonzero?

Comment: Also this wouldn't be row equivalent if $a =b$, $b = c$, or $a = c$.

Comment: I think you need to add the assumption that $a$, $b$, $c$ are distinct, else you matrix has at least two identical rows and can't be equivalent to $I$.  Cheers!

Comment: Key phrase: vandermonde matrix/determinant.